# Print a binary search tree with depth

Tags: c, printing, tree, binary-search-tree

i need to print a binary search tree with depth and from high to low, 
depending on the depth increases the number of dashes before printing the node. The root of the tree go with 0 dashes, her silbings go with one dash...
I can print the tree without the dashes but i dont have idea how to print with the dashes.
Im using C.
SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving this. Recursive or keeping the depth in nodes.

1- You could use a recursive code like following

```
void printnode (bststruct *node, int depth)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=depth;i++) printf("-");
    printf("%d\n",node->value);
    if(node->left !=null) printnode(node->left,depth+1);
    if(node->right !=null) printnode(node->right,depth+1);
}
```

and in your main function or whichever function you run for this operation, just call `printnode(root,0)`.

2- Another way is to keep a dedicated value for depth in each node. If you are not going to use that value for any other purposes, just do the first option.